# Shopify Customer Login

Tags: android, authentication, shopify, verification

I am new at **shopify** 
I am working on customer login of **shopify** in android app.
I want to check credentials of user before **login**.
So is there any way to do it?

Comment: Your question is very broad and nearly impossible to answer in an useful way. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

you used shared prefrences if first time login username ,password store in sharedprefrances next time check get data from shared prefrences.

public class Prefs {
    static Context mContext;

```
public static void setPreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {
    mContext = context;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences(
            "ParkZap", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getPreferences(Context context, String key) {
    mContext = context;
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("ParkZap",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String position = prefs.getString(key, "");
    return position;
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your comment but how can i verify my credentials  data with shopify databse...

Comment: dude first time you login then check from your shopify server after status success then store user info to prefrences

Comment: actually buddy i dont know how to check it with shopify server.. please help me with that...

Comment: if you locally store register user deatils then check it with your local database if you register with server then check with server api ,

Comment: where i can find that server api of shopify.. I dont have that api... please if you have that api.. please share with me..